# Viewcomponent inside foreach iteration loops keeps returns the same data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am making a webpage inside a MVC net core app where a user adds furniture to their room. The page uses a foreach loop to make bootstrap nav-pills that hold viewcomponents inside. The viewcomponents are filtered by the type of furniture (enum inside the Furniture model) to return a simple list of furniture of that specified type

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    @foreach (Furniture.FurnitureType FurType in (Namjestaj.FurnitureType [])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Furniture.FurnitureType )))
    {
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#@(FurType )">@(FurType )</a></li>
    }
</ul>
  @foreach  (Furniture.FurnitureType FurType in (Namjestaj.FurnitureType [])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Furniture.FurnitureType )))
    {
        <div id="@(FurnitureType )" class="tab-pane fade">
            <p>@(FurnitureType )</p>         
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("RoomFurniture", new { id = Model.Id, FurnitureType= FurType , free= true })            
         </div>
    }
```

//viewcomponet code

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int id, Furniture.FurnitureType typ, bool free)
{
   List<Furniture> furniture= db.Furniture.Where(x => x.FurnitureType == typ).ToList();  
   return View("RoomFurniture", furniture);
}
```

The viewcomponent return the result but it always keeps returning the same result. Out of all the furniture types ("couch","bed","table"...) it returns only the beds in every nav-pill. I have even tried to hard code a different type but only keeps returning beds. Inside the debugger the foreach loop iterates properly and inside the razor page the Viewcoponent gets the right enum value, but the invokeAsync function still stays set on "bed".

Answer (score 0):

Your enumeration result does not map to `Furniture.FurnitureType` correctly, that is why it always returns first enum value.

Comment: Where excatly, can you please specify?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the worked sample , note that keep the `href`of `<a></a>` consistent with the `id` of `<div></div>`

Furniture.cs

```
 public class Furniture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FurName { get; set; }
    public FurnitureType FurnitureType { get; set; }
}

public enum FurnitureType
{
    bed,
    couch,
    table
}
```

Main view code

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
        @foreach (FurnitureType FurType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FurnitureType)))
        {
            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#@(FurType )">@(FurType )</a></li>
        }
</ul>
    @foreach (FurnitureType FurType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FurnitureType)))
    {
        <div id="@(FurType )" class="tab-pane fade">
            <p>@(FurType)</p>
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("RoomFurniture", new {furnitureType = FurType, free = true })
        </div>
    }
```

RoomFurnitureViewComponent.cs

```
 public IViewComponentResult Invoke(FurnitureType furnitureType, bool free)
    {
        List<Furniture> furniture = _context.Furniture.Where(x => x.FurnitureType == furnitureType).ToList();
        return View(furniture);
    }
```

The default.cshtml of viewcomponent

```
@model List<MVC2_1Test.Models.Furniture>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Default";
}


<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            FurName
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FurName)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  
1. I cant just use the FurType directly inside the foreach, I am using the "@using ISZR.Web.Models" to be able to access the model (it isn't being sent via the controller) thus obj.FurnitureType is necessary.  
2.Sedcond off all removing the "(Namjestaj.FurnitureType [])" from the enumerations only changes the enum values from text to numbers.
My code works properly when it comes to the pill creation.I am also using the "@Html.Action to see if the route values are set properly, which they are.
Url.Action Generates "Area/Controller/Function/id=1,type="couch",free=true

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem. You can get it to work by making a copy of the value during each iteration:

```
@foreach  (Furniture.FurnitureType FurType in (Namjestaj.FurnitureType [])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Furniture.FurnitureType )))
{
    var furType = FurType;
    <div id="@(FurnitureType )" class="tab-pane fade">
        <p>@(FurnitureType )</p>         
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("RoomFurniture", new { id = Model.Id, FurnitureType = furType, free= true })            
     </div>
}
```